# How do I update to latest version?

Tags: 8, updating

I used [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) to install Drupal 8. Drupal 8.4.7 was installed, and the website was functioning as expected.

Today, I got the message that Drupal 8.5 was ready for prime time, so I did some research and found [Update core via Composer (option 4)](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer-option-4) for updating code.

This is not updating core.

Comment: Indeed, the described proceedings of your linked option 4 would upgrade Drupal core, if the version restraints from your `composer.json` and installed dependencies allow it. Therefore it's very hard to answering your question. As there is neither a real question in it, nor do you describe a real issue/what went wrong while you tried the upgrade. Please provide more details. (E.g. error messages, the require/require-dev sections of your `composer.json` and a description of your issue.)

Answer (score 3):

The instructions to update Drupal when you used drupal-composer/drupal-project as Composer template are given in their [README.md](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/blob/8.x/README.md).

> 1. Run `composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev symfony/* --with-dependencies` to update Drupal Core and its dependencies
> 2. Run `git diff` to determine if any of the scaffolding files have changed. Review the files for any changes and restore any customizations to .htaccess or robots.txt
> 3. Commit everything all together in a single commit, so web will remain in sync with the core when checking out branches or running `git bisect`
> 4. In the event that there are non-trivial conflicts in step 2, you may wish to perform these steps on a branch, and use git merge to combine the updated core files with your customized files. This facilitates the use of [a three-way merge tool such as kdiff3](http://www.gitshah.com/2010/12/how-to-setup-kdiff-as-diff-tool-for-git.html). This setup is not necessary if your changes are simple; keeping all of your modifications at the beginning or end of the file is a good strategy to keep merges easy.

You need to at least to follow the first two steps. The other two are necessary for a particular setup.

Answer (score 0):

Option 4 is when you have composer installed and working.

I have tried this way:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-manually-via-cli-option-2

Comment: Since the OP is using a Composer template, Composer must be installed and working.

Answer (score 0):

In your drupal 8 root issue the following commands:

```
rm -rf vendor/
rm -rf sites/default/files/php/    
composer require drupal/core    
composer update
drush updb 
drush cr
```

If it does not work just copy the files overwriting the old ones as usual...